# Can I combine two Linq calls when they use different syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code. The function has a lot of Linq calls and I had help on putting this into place.

```
    public IList<Content.Grid> Details(string pk)
    {
        IEnumerable<Content.Grid> details = null;
        IList<Content.Grid> detailsList = null;
        var data = _contentRepository.GetPk(pk);
        var refType = this.GetRefType(pk);
        var refStat = this.GetRefStat(pk);
        var type = _referenceRepository.GetPk(refType);
        var stat = _referenceRepository.GetPk(refStat);
        details =
        from d in data
        join s in stat on d.Status equals s.RowKey into statuses
        from s in statuses.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join t in type on d.Type equals t.RowKey into types
        from t in types.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new Content.Grid
        {
            PartitionKey = d.PartitionKey,
            RowKey = d.RowKey,
            Order = d.Order,
            Title = d.Title,
            Status = s == null ? null : s.Value,
            StatusKey = d.Status,
            Type = t == null ? null : t.Value,
            TypeKey = d.Type,
            Link = d.Link,
            Notes = d.Notes,
            TextLength = d.TextLength
        };
        detailsList = details
                .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
                .ThenBy(item => item.Title)
                .Select((t, index) => new Content.Grid()
                {
                    PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey,
                    RowKey = t.RowKey,
                    Row = index + 1,
                    Order = t.Order,
                    Title = t.Title,
                    Status = t.Status,
                    StatusKey = t.StatusKey,
                    Type = t.Type,
                    TypeKey = t.TypeKey,
                    Link = t.Link,
                    Notes = t.Notes,
                    TextLength = t.TextLength,

                })
                 .ToList();
        return detailsList;

    }
```

The first uses one format for Linq and the second another. Is there some way that I could simplify and/or combine these? I would really like to make this code simpler but I am not sure how to do this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: the *result* is the same, regardless of LINQ comprehension vs using the extension methods / lambdas. If what you have *works*, you could argue: stop changing it ;p

Comment: If I was to change the second part then would I be able to combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can combine them. The Linq keywords such as `from`, `where` and `select` get translated into calls like the Extension methods that you call below, so effectively there's no difference.

If you really want to combine them, the quickest way is to put `()` around the first query, then append the method calls you use on `details` in the second query. Like this:

```
detailsList =
        (from d in data                    // <-- The first query
         // ...
         select new Content.Grid
         {
             // ...
         })
         .OrderBy(item => item.Order)    // <-- The calls from the second query
         .ThenBy(item => item.Title)
         .Select((t, index) => new Content.Grid()
         {
             //...
         }).ToList();
```

But i think that would be ugly. Two queries are just fine IMO.